# Plot igraph arranging the nodes in a circle (placing those with greater strength in the center)

Tags: r, igraph

The following data frame `df` contains a symbolic edge list in the first two columns. The third is the edge attributes (weight):

```
structure(list(from = list("crot", "gen", "leice", "ro", "sivi", 
    "sp", "uni", "int", "mil", "mil", "sampd", "virtus ", "cremo", 
    "atal", "mil", "porde", "cremo", "bres", "juve", "laz", "bres", 
    "laz", "mil", "atal", "atal", "car", "mon", "sampd", "sudt", 
    "vice", "vene", "atal", "atal", "manchest", "al-", "gen", 
    "stade ", "mil", "atal", "mil", "franco", "olymp ", "palme", 
    "sivi", "tor", "mil", "cremo", "vene", "vene", "juve", "mil", 
    "mil", "laz", "atal", "juve", "sp", "juve", "mil", "bres", 
    "b. geru", "laz", "par", "laz", "vene", "mil", "vene", "bres", 
    "fiore", "vene"), to = list("atal", "atal", "atal", "atal", 
    "atal", "atal", "atal", "b.dor", "bod/g", "bres", "bres", 
    "bres", "ces", "chel", "chel", "citta", "cose", "dinamo z", 
    "ever", "f.c. sou", "fc gro", "fener", "franco", "ge", "gir", 
    "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "juve s", "juve", "juve", 
    "juve", "laz", "laz", "laz", "lion", "lokotiv", "manches", 
    "mil", "mil", "mil", "mil", "mil", "olymp.", "peru", "peru", 
    "piac", "psv ein", "real m", "rsc and", "salern", "sampd", 
    "santo", "sass", "shalk", "sivi", "slask w", "sp", "sp", 
    "sp", "sp", "spe", "tor", "trap", "tur", "vene", "vkin"), 
    weight = c(1e+05, 2e+05, 2e+07, 2.1e+07, 5e+06, 5500000, 
    21300000, 7e+07, 4800000, 1e+07, 5e+05, 2e+06, 1e+05, 14500000, 
    6e+05, 2e+06, 7e+05, 1e+06, 7e+06, 1e+06, 450000, 19920000, 
    6700000, 1.2e+07, 520000, 50000, 4e+05, 4e+05, 1e+05, 4e+05, 
    1e+06, 9320000, 1.9e+07, 1.5e+07, 5e+05, 1950000, 4500000, 
    1190000, 14500000, 5e+05, 3e+06, 2e+07, 2e+06, 2.1e+07, 1950000, 
    1e+06, 250000, 3e+05, 150000, 1900000, 2e+05, 5250000, 12700000, 
    6e+05, 1500000, 4500000, 20500000, 3680000, 6e+05, 1e+06, 
    8e+06, 4900000, 8e+06, 2e+05, 5e+05, 20000, 33000, 7e+05, 
    5e+05)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -69L), groups = structure(list(to = list(
    "atal", "b.dor", "bod/g", "bres", "ces", "chel", "citta", 
    "cose", "dinamo z", "ever", "f.c. sou", "fc gro", "fener", 
    "franco", "ge", "gir", "int", "juve s", "juve", "laz", "lion", 
    "lokotiv", "manches", "mil", "olymp.", "peru", "piac", "psv ein", 
    "real m", "rsc and", "salern", "sampd", "santo", "sass", 
    "shalk", "sivi", "slask w", "sp", "spe", "tor", "trap", "tur", 
    "vene", "vkin"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8L, 9L, 10:12, 
    13L, 14:15, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26:30, 31L, 32:34, 35:37, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41:45, 46L, 
    47:48, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
    59L, 60:63, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -44L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I would like to plot the graph from this dataframe and so:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations_tot, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
igraph.options(plot.layout=layout.circle, vertex.size=5)
plot(g)
```

I used the layaout that arranges the nodes in a circle:
[image]
I would like to place thos nodes with highest `strength` in the center of the graph. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below using `which.max` to locate the vertex with largest `strength` and assign its location to the origin, e.g.,

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations_tot, directed = TRUE, vertices = actors)
lo <- layout_in_circle(g)
idx <- which.max(V(g)$strength)
lo[idx, ] <- 0
plot(g, layout = lo, vertex.size = 5)
```